# Accessing the shared folder in XP using TCL without mapping to a drive

Tags: windows, file, tcl, unc

I want to access the shared folder and copy some files from it to the local machine. I tried it using the file copy command in TCL, with the shared location being mapped to a drive, which works. How can I access it without mapping it explicitly to a drive?

```
\\192.168.2.10\test\test1.txt
```

When I map this is to a drive, say `Y:`, I was able to do the `file copy` command in TCL.
But is there a way, where I can do it without mapping it to a drive?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the [“long” form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention)? It might work…

```
\\?\UNC\192.168.2.10\test\test1.txt
```

Note also that Tcl uses `\` as an escape character; you might need to take special care when generating the filename. (When debugging, print the filename to the console before using it just so you know *exactly* what you're working with; that will avoid much trouble!) You might find that the [`file nativename`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/file.htm) command helps with this.

Comment: Simple `file stat {\\machinename\c$\foobar} stat` works OK for me. Same command with `{\\?\UNC\machinename\c$\foobar}` doesn't.  So I think the original poster actually answered his/her question, and the problem is really about preserving those backslashes as you rightfully guessed.

Answer (score 0):

actually, simply using xcopy and the full path to the share works (at least if the share is not password protected).

So, `xcopy \\192.168.2.10\test\test1.txt c:\temp` would copy the test file to your C:\Temp folder.